# Unity Blurry at Low Resolution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I wanted to test out if I could set the game resolution as very low and get the desired retro style NES graphical style. When I set the resolution, everything is very blurry. I turned off the Anti Aliasing and the texture has no filtering.

```
 void Start() {
    Screen.SetResolution(256, 240, true);
    MR.transform.gameObject.active = false;
    StartCoroutine(MakeRectangle());
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2), "This is a box");
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: if this helps: when you expand something in the viewer to be bigger than it's resolution, it gets blurry. HOWEVER, when you make the camera viewport smaller to fit the smaller object, it will not be blurry.

Comment: but that shouldn't affect GUI.Box right??

Comment: Yes it can effect anything. If the text object is small, but was scaled up instead of setting the actual object to be bigger, then it will be blurry.

Comment: I'll try this I guess, thanks man!

Comment: Please stop using `OnGui` and start using [the new ui](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui).

Comment: I know, but i didnt want to be limited by the crappy UI textures for buttons etc